# Why does LD strip debug information when combining my object files?

Tags: c, linker, embedded, ld, debug-symbols

I have a linker script that pulls together lots of object files. The relevant part looks like this:

```
.usr {
    Build/usr/*.o
} > sdram
```

All the object files (Build/usr/*o) have debug information in them (this can be verified with `objdump -S`, which shows the correspondence between C line numbers and disassembly).

However, debug information for the code in the `.usr` section was not present in the resulting elf file.

As an experiment, I changed the relevant section to look like this:

```
.usr : {
   Build/usr/*(.text);
   Build/usr/*(.data);
   Build/usr/*(.bss COMMON);
 } > sdram
```

And the problem went away.

Can anyone suggest why this solved the problem?

Comment: Apologies - not sure how to fix the syntax hilighting.

Comment: Should also clarify that this is all with the GNU toolchain for an ARM target.